# Authentication failing in RESTful test

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, testing

I have created my own authentication middleware that accepts an Authorization header which is used to query the `api_tokens` table to find a matching token and checks expiry.

This is working fine when testing manually but the automated tests are doing something strange. My tests basically look like this:

```
public function testGetLocation()
{
    $user = factory(\App\Models\User::class, 'userA')->create();
    $token = factory(\App\Models\ApiToken::class, 'userA-token')-create();
    $location = factory(\App\Models\Location::class, 'userA-location1')->create();

    $this->json('GET', '/api/location/'.$location->id, [], ['Authorization' => 'Bearer '. $token->token])
         ->assertStatus(200);
}
```

However when I run the test I receive a 500 error saying that column `users.api_token` doesn't exist. I have removed this column from the user table as it's not longer required. If I put it back in I don't receive an error but the test user can't authenticate. Obviously Laravel or phpunit are somehow ignoring the auth that I am trying to use. I can't see where.

After searching Google I have tried things others have mentioned such as adding `actingAs($user)` and `$this->be()` but this hasn't helped.

Any suggestions?

Edit: The MySQL log show that this query is being executed:

```
select * from `users` where `api_token` = 'userA-token' limit 1
```

Laravel should not be searching the api_token in the users table. This is not a result from my code so I am lost.

Edit 2: My `routes/api.php` looks like this:

```
Route::group([
    'prefix' => 'api',
    //'middleware' => 'auth:api'
    'middleware' => 'ApiTokenAuthentication',
], function () {
```

This is definitely being called because I can output vars here during tests. But it seems that the standard auth is being called also, despite it not being included anywhere in the routes.

Comment: have you tried `auth()->login($user)` global function?

Comment: I have now but no change. Thanks though.

Answer (score 0):

In `routes/api.php` replace `auth:api` in

```
Route::middleware('auth:api')
//or 
Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth:api'])
```

With your own middleware.

When using this laravel default `auth:api` middleware, it queries the `users` table for `api_token`.

Comment: Thanks. I forgot to show my routing code in my initial question. I've done that now with an edit. My middleware is being called, but also is the default Laravel one despite being commented out.

Comment: OK, I've proved that default Laravel `auth` midddleware is being called by commented out the line `'auth' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\Authenticate::class,` in the `$routeMiddleware` array in `app/Http/Kernel` which causes a new 500 error because it can't be instantiated.  I can prevent this by adding `use WithoutMiddleware` in the test file, but this also prevents my middleware from running. Is there a way to control which is not run?

Comment: I can't really but I think the issue is that Laravel is forcing regular auth to run when it shouldn't. I just need to disable that and all should be fine,

Answer (score 0):

if you wanna to disable default laravel api middleware for api file edit app/Providers/RouteServiceProvider.php file and mapApiRoutes function like this :

```
protected function mapApiRoutes()
{
    Route::group([
        'middleware' => 'YOUR_CUSTOME_MIDDLEWARE',
        'namespace' => $this->namespace,
        'prefix' => 'api',
    ], function ($router) {
        require base_path('routes/api.php');
    });
}
```